# Refused to load _framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js after upgrading visual studio to 16.10.0

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor, content-security-policy, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on `.net 5 blazor wasm` project. I recently updated my `Visual Studio 2019` to version `16.10.0`. All of a sudden I started getting an error message in my browser (Google Chrome) `console` as shown below:

> Refused to load the script
> 'https://localhost:44340/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "script-src 'sha256-fa5rxHhZ799izGRP38+h4ud5QXNT0SFaFlh4eqDumBI='".
> Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is
> used as a fallback.

I don't have `_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js` added in my `index.html`. Here is the scripts and styles declaration in my `index.html`

`styles` declared inside `<head>` in `index.html`:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>App</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Web.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="_content/BlazorDateRangePicker/daterangepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="icon-512.png" />
</head>
```

`scripts` in `index.html`:

```html
<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="js/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="js/print.js"></script>
<script src="js/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorDateRangePicker/clickAndPositionHandler.js"></script>
<script src="js/blazorInterop.js"></script>
<script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
```

But when I launch the app via `visual studio`, from the browser I can see that `_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js` gets appended to scripts section in my `index.html`. Here is the screen print.

[image: index.html source]

This is anything related to my configuration error? or I need to setup CSP in my `index.html`? Please assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like `/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js` script [belongs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/51126#issuecomment-817134047) to a new [Hot Reload](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/) feature.

Something was broken due to upgrade because message: `it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'sha256-fa5rxHhZ799izGRP38+h4ud5QXNT0SFaFlh4eqDumBI='"` says thay you have CSP `script-src 'sha256-fa5rxHhZ799izGRP38+h4ud5QXNT0SFaFlh4eqDumBI='`, but at the same time you load a lot of scripts:

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="js/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="js/print.js"></script>
<script src="js/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorDateRangePicker/clickAndPositionHandler.js"></script>
<script src="js/blazorInterop.js"></script>
<script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
```

At least you need to have `'self'` in the `script-src` directive. Also the *sha256-fa5rxHhZ799izGRP38+h4ud5QXNT0SFaFlh4eqDumBI=* hash value does not match the [hash](https://csplite.com/csp/sha/?pl=eJxLtDK0qi62MrFS8gjx9VGyLrYyN7RSsilOLsosKLHLSyzLTE8syS%2FSK04tKstMTg3PL8pOLdIrSk3PLC5JLdJQh4rrlkMksorVNa1t9KHalaxrASauIX0%3D#result) of your navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js'); inline script.

You should have a lot of CSP errors in the console.

Comment: But the question is how to mitigate the CSP with this hot reload script? We can't add a hash to the CSP, because we'd need to add `integrity` attribute to the script element as well. The only way seems to be to add 'self' which we may not want to.